# Your app contains embedded private keys or keystore files org/bouncycastle/openssl/test/data/dsa/openssl_dsa_aes128_cbc.pem

Tags: android

I cannot find any .pem file in the library or in my project. But when I extract my apk I could able to see those file. How to get rid of this

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your build.gradle file.

```
android {
    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'your/path/to/file/FILE_NAME.pem'
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I finally found that library and removed that. Thank you

Comment: That Might. But I haven't tried. Just removed that library which has that pem file, coz no longer needed.